# Could the child element hide() parent?

Tags: jquery

Could child element hide parent?

```
<ul class="parent">
 <li>email@email.com <span class="sp">delete</span></li>
</ul>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(".sp").click(function(){
 $('.parent li').hide();
});
```

With this jQuery code the "li" couldnt be hide.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but your code here will hide every `li` witin a `.parent` in the whole page.  Presumably you just want to hide the parent element of the clicked element.

For this, use [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent):

```
$('.sp').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

[See a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/eDwfz/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it?

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/KFb2d/

or try:

```
$(".sp").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sp").click(function() { $(this).parent().hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do it:

```
$(".sp").parent().hide()
```